# React 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am displaying my application using:

```
React.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

The server is displaying at port 3000.

However, whenever I access

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

The browser displays

```
Cannot GET /
```

Comment: `Cannot GET /` represents an issue with your server.  Do you have more information about that?

Comment: Did you attach anything to the `GET /` route? doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

React.render() produces a string for display, but doesn't bind it to any routes.  you'll need to address that part of your application before worrying about React.  I recommend using the basic express generator template, and then start adding react to that.